# Lord Shiva and Brahmavadis

Tags: scripture, shiva, krishna, guru, iskcon

[From the lecture of HG Anogh Lila Prabhu](https://youtu.be/0n13r73pwP8)

3:25-5:01

HG makes mention of Lord Shiva training Brahmavadis in 4 courses.Can someone give a reference to this claim?

Comment: Firstly, not the downvoter. Secondly, you can ask anything you like citing any videos you want but if you are trying to learn about Lord Shiva from the discourse of that preacher then I must say that it's a very bad source.

Comment: Thank you Rickross.I am not taking that single discourse only.I’ve heard this lecture a couple of times,and there are some facts and statements that HG says,I was curious and wanted to know the validity of these.Thank you for your advice.@Rickross.

Comment: Yes alright. I'm not only talking about the particular video but generally about the preacher. He is not the best person to give lectures on Lord Shiva. But you are still free to ask questions related to what he says in his discourses.